# addEvent giving null event object

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events, internet-explorer-8, addeventlistener

I'm trying to get IE8 support in a project of mine and having a tough time converting addEventListener to addEvent (from: http://ejohn.org/projects/flexible-javascript-events/)

So, with his code I have an event setup like ([source here](https://github.com/OscarGodson/EpicEditor/blob/dc5daed944c518bb7dcebc5d37de1990cddd6865/epiceditor/js/epiceditor.js#L854-L856)):

```
_addEvent(eventableIframes[i], 'mousemove', function (e) {
  utilBarHandler(e);
});
```

However, when it gets to `utilBarHandler`, "`e`" is `null` and IE8 gives me an "object required" error [here on line 783](https://github.com/OscarGodson/EpicEditor/blob/dc5daed944c518bb7dcebc5d37de1990cddd6865/epiceditor/js/epiceditor.js#L783). I'm assuming the object required is the event object since its literally just null when I log out `e` at the [top of the function](https://github.com/OscarGodson/EpicEditor/blob/dc5daed944c518bb7dcebc5d37de1990cddd6865/epiceditor/js/epiceditor.js#L777).

Also, this happens for every event in that loop that requires the event object such as `shortcutHandler` and `shortcutUpHandler`.

Update: just in case people are missing it, this post has a bunch of links that highlight specific lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all versions of IE pass the event as an argument.  It's in `window.event`.  You can add this to your _addEvent shim or to your event handler:

```
 e = e || window.event
```

as in:

```
_addEvent(eventableIframes[i], 'mousemove', function (e) {
      e = e || window.event;
      utilBarHandler(e);
});
```

which will work in either IE or others.

Here's two flavors of a cross browser event handling that makes sure both the `event` and the `this` pointer are set appropriately in IE:

```
// add event cross browser
function addEvent(elem, event, fn) {
    if (elem.addEventListener) {
        elem.addEventListener(event, fn, false);
    } else {
        elem.attachEvent("on" + event, function() {
            // set the this pointer same as addEventListener when fn is called
            return(fn.call(elem, window.event));   
        });
    }
}


// refined add event cross browser
function addEvent(elem, event, fn) {
    // avoid memory overhead of new anonymous functions for every event handler that's installed
    // by using local functions
    function listenHandler(e) {
        var ret = fn.apply(this, arguments);
        if (ret === false) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        return(ret);
    }

    function attachHandler() {
        // set the this pointer same as addEventListener when fn is called
        // and make sure the event is passed to the fn also so that works the same too
        var ret = fn.call(elem, window.event);   
        if (ret === false) {
            window.event.returnValue = false;
            window.event.cancelBubble = true;
        }
        return(ret);
    }

    if (elem.addEventListener) {
        elem.addEventListener(event, listenHandler, false);
    } else {
        elem.attachEvent("on" + event, attachHandler);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, so I tried your first simple example and it didn't work. Same `null` issue. I also put `e = e || window.event` as you said and I'm still seeing `e` as `null`. I put a console.log above `e = e || window.event` and below it to see if it changed anything and it didn't. Maybe this is a different issue?

Comment: FYI, you can see the result here: https://img.skitch.com/20120812-xs9b3u4djqjjftuw4k72buy3hp.png

Comment: @OscarGodson - you'll have to show the full piece of code.  Your screen shot just shows `utilBarHandler`, but not how it's hooked up to the event and also we don't have the code for your `_addEvent()` function.

Comment: All the code is linked above in my OP. I link to specific lines as well as the whole file. You can clone the repo too if you want to see it in action. The screenshot was just showing the small example.

Comment: @OscarGodson - I don't know.  There's something screwy, but I don't see exactly what it is.  I'd have to have an actual web page with the non-working code in it that I could step through in IE to offer further info.  I'd suggest you isolate the issue to a very small piece of code in a jsFiddle.  If that doesn't help you figure out yourself where the problem is, then you can post the jsFiddle here for us to debug ourselves.  FYI that Resig event handling code is pretty old (2005) and designed to work in obsolete browsers (like IE5).  Simpler things will work today.

Comment: Yeah I'm fine with anything else. I know it's old it's just what's suggested everywhere. Do you have any other suggestions? Also you can just do a clone of the repo and checkout feature/ticket-4 to see the error. I can also just upload it for you too somewhere I'd you want

Comment: @OscarGodson - I have already put my own version of `addEvent()` in my answer that is more modern.  I like the second one of the two I offered.  My suggestion beyond that is in my previous comment here.

Comment: Yeah, I swapped out the code but still get a null event like I said :\

Comment: @OscarGodson - then it has to do with something around the event code (how you're using it), not the event code itself.  If you can give me a working version that shows the problem, I can step through it myself in IE and likely see what's going on.  Use a jsFiddle or post a link to a public site with instructions for how to trigger the issue.

Comment: here you go: http://jsbin.com/uqenug/1/ -- hovering over the editor or pressing key commands will trigger the error in IE8

Comment: @OscarGodson - it doesn't even startup properly in IE for me (several script errors during initialization).  I can't get to the part you describe.

Comment: Is it in quirks mode? JSBin triggers quirksmode in IE. Change it to IE8 rendering mode and you will see the errors: https://img.skitch.com/20120814-bx435qh23k9m6g6g2g7r7ca7ug.png

Comment: Also, it wont fully load in IE8 because of the object required errors so you wont actually see the editor, just a white page, but hovering where it'd be will trigger the errors. A fresh clone of the repo still might be easiest as it shouldn't trigger quirks mode and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty fix that @jfriend00 suggested, `e = e || window.event`, was 99% the way there but I was still having issues. After more fiddling I found the answer. I didn't want `window.event` because it was an iframe. Instead I wanted `iframeElement.contentWindow`. Adding it into my callbacks like this did the trick:

```
_addEvent(eventableIframes[i], 'mousemove', function (e) {
  // self.iframeElement == <iframe>
  e = e || self.iframeElement.contentWindow;
  utilBarHandler(e);
});
```